# Why different gauges of wire in homes?

Tags: electrical

From what I understand as I learn about home wiring, different gauges of wire are used on different circuits in the house based on anticipated loads.

Is there a reason that some rooms are intentionally wired to support only lower loads?  Would there be any disadvantage to wiring an entire house with wire that could support, say, 80 amp loads?

Comment: Cost and danger.  Need quite big expensive wire gauge for 80 amps and if something happen to a 100w light fixture, it would take a long time for a 80 amp breaker to trip, causing a fire.  Imagine welding without using a welder in a house.

Comment: No problem you could do it if you want but why, nothing will match, the value will be reduced, it would not pass inspection etc. What are you going to use for receptacles etc.  How about the plugs on you appliances etc what will you connect them to. It will be interesting to see you wire a house with the required wire for 80 amps. I suggest you get a book on basic wiring and see if that answers your question. What about the items that depend on the branch circuit protection to prevent fires.  A lot of people smarter than I am have worked the basic recommendations and requirements for a reason.

Comment: There is some logic  to your idea, there are areas that run a single larger feed to feed a larger area then put appropriate sized smaller fuses at  the point of attaching devices.

Comment: Copper and aluminum are precious metals. And crack is expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 100A breakers won't protect small appliances

It is North American / UL policy to have breaker sizes reasonably match load sizes.  Thus a 22A dryer requires a 30A breaker and no other size.

You're talking about wiring ready for 80A loads, which means after the 125% derate, 100A breaker.

That will not protect a small appliance.  Imagine you have a table saw which has a LRA of 80 amps (Locked Rotor Amperage) meaning it draws 80A for the milliseconds as the motor starts, until back EMF builds up to resist current.  You jam the blade, it stalls, and you step away from it to get a tool to un-jam it (or to get first aid for a minor injury).  *You forgot to turn it off*.

The motor has a Locked Rotor, so it's drawing 80A.  Normally that is on a 15A or 20A breaker, which will tolerate an 80A surge *for a few seconds* (to allow motor startup) but will trip after that. So the protection works.

In your scenario, a 100A breaker is simpatico with 80A being drawn.  So it would sit there at 80 LRA, overheating the motor (it can't cool 80A even with its cooling fan turning) and soon sets the sawdust on fire.

### You would need fuses in each plug

And the UK does that -- in fact, when you consider their **ring mains**, they do pretty much your whole strategy.  They wire a circuit with 16-amp wire, in a ring - from the breaker, round the house, and back to the breaker. The breaker is 32A since it can feed both ways (is their logic).   But their key safety weapon is a fuse in the socket *which is keyed to the appliance's actual needs*.  The UK version of that saw would have 7 running amps, LRA of 40 amps, and a 10A slow-blow fuse.   It would blow within 20 seconds at 40A.

### The cost would really suck

So we're talking #1 aluminum ($1.50/foot) or #3 copper ($5/foot) on all circuits.  There would be fewer circuits so less circuity (ser-cue-i-tee: a zig-zagging, roundabout path).  You wouldn't have 3 circuits of wires passing through the same wall, or a bundle of 16 cables all crossing the length of the house to get to the panel.  But that would not nearly make up for the cost.

Also, wire bending radius rules require a rather large junction box for #1 aluminum wire (and it would be madness to attempt to use copper, and aluminum that large has always served reliably). So a typical switch or receptacle box would span most of the width of a stud bay.  The cover plate would be *enormous*.

The lugs would need to be the monsters that you tighten down with a hex key and a torque wrench, which means a random receptacle or switch would cost about what a 100A pullout disconnect switch costs.

The bending curves would also make routing the wires in the walls a royal pain.

### Strategic use of sub panels provide much of that benefit

I generally dislike seeing houses with a fat trunk of a dozen #12 or #14 cables running a long distance across a house.  In my view, uses tend to be in clusters - typically around a pair of bathrooms, a kitchen, laundry, garage etc.  So the way I see it, right in the middle of that cluster should be a *sub-panel*.  Run your 100A wire to the subpanel (cheap #2 aluminum being good for 90A) and then have *short* runs of #12 or #14 to the points of use nearby.

Answer (score 6):

#### TL:DR Money

Thicker wire costs more. 14 AWG (15A) to 12 AWG (20A) isn't so bad, so using 12 AWG everywhere as Harper suggests, can be reasonable for repairs and upgrades. But anything larger, or wiring a whole new house with 12 when 14 will do (especially for lighting circuits) is a big extra expense with no benefit.

At much larger sizes there are other problems such as conduit fill and bending radius. Plus your standard 15A and 20A switches, receptacles and appliances will typically have screw connectors that can handle at most one extra size up (10 AWG), so then you'd have to pigtail all the large wires to small wires, probably needing larger boxes in some cases as well.

You might think that by using larger wire, you can use larger breakers and then connect more *stuff*. But most stuff that most people have (in the US) is plugged in to standard receptacles, which are only rated for use on 15A or 20A circuits. So you can't make those circuits larger than 20A no matter how large the wire is. Hardwired loads often have more leeway, but for most people that is lighting (which actually needs very little power - a single 15A circuit can power an entire house full of LED lighting) and a few appliances. Some of those appliances will already be on larger circuits anyway (HVAC, oven, water heater) and the ones that are not normally on larger circuits (dishwasher, disposal, etc.) may have instructions that say they *must* be on a 15A or 20A circuit (not smaller or larger) and you must follow instructions unless you have a specific allowed exception.

A typical house has wiring **everywhere** but only a handful of circuits larger than 20A - water heater, dryer, oven, HVAC and EV charger. Many have only some of those. I have a gas water heater, a gas cooktop and no EV charger, so only 3 > 20A circuits - dryer, oven and HVAC.